# Rendering problems: The following classes could not be found

Tags: android, xml, rendering

I am trying to reuse a piece of code from another app which is working perfectly fine. It is about displaying a rounded image. Here is my XML file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/background_color"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="3sp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <com.myname.myportal.utilities.RoundedImageView
                android:id="@+id/category_image"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:border_color="@color/divider"
                app:border_width="0dip"
                app:is_oval="true"
                app:round_background="true" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/category_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="@color/text_color" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

The error I get is

> The following classes could not be found:
>   - com.myname.myportal.utilities.RoundedImageView

although I'm 100% sure that file is created and working properly (as it's been copied from another app). If I `Ctrl+Space` on the file it opens correctly. The only error I get is `Cannot resolve symbol 'R'` but I'm assuming it's because `R` cannot be generated due to the errors on the XML file, right?

Comment: Check your class namespace, make sure that it corresponds to the one in the XML layout.

Comment: I have tripled-checked that. It is the same.

Comment: Is `com.myname.myportal.utilities.RoundedImageView` a custom view?

Comment: @DanielK yes, I took it from another project. The only error I get inside the `RoundedImageView` class is `Cannot resolve symbol 'R'`, which I assume happens due to the errors on the XML layout.

Comment: Do you have the library for that view anywhere in your project?

Comment: And can you show me where the original project is? That is if it is online of course.

Comment: By library do you mean the dependencies on the gradle build file? I did use the same as the original project there. Unfortunately, it is a project I've bought to study and build my own app, so can't link it.

Comment: @user3484582, Look at the source for custom view and make sure you move it over to your new project. It may be a gradle dependency, it may not. It doesn't sound like it is.

Comment: @DanielK the custom view is using 2 files which I've made sure to move over to my project. I fixed the package name on both of them. I used the same dependencies. Could I PM you the original project so you could take a look and give me a hand?

Comment: @user3484582, absolutely.

Comment: @DanielK found your email through GitHub, hope you don't mind. Contacted you there.

Comment: @user3484582, I got your email, I'll review the app in a little while & get back to you. I just realized you couldn't receive or send PMs on this site too whoops.

Comment: @DanielK Yeah, that's why I searched for your email. Can't thank you enough, please take your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, from the original project, copy the following files to your project:

```
/utilities/RoundedDrawable.java
/utilities/RoundedImageView.java
/res/values/attrs.xml
```

Then you add it in a layout with this tag:

```
<packagename.RoundedImageView
    <!-- XML attributes --> />
```

Here is an example that I had in my test app:

```
<com.danielkaparunakis.stackoverflowquestions.RoundedImageView
        android:id="@+id/category_image"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:border_color="#000000"
        app:border_width="0dip"
        app:is_oval="true"
        app:round_background="true" />
```

Comment: I appreciate it for taking the time to look at it! It seems all I missed was copying the `attrs.xml` file. Works perfectly now.

Comment: @user3484582, no problem, I think that was all as well.